# AngularJS - controller executes before controller has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular automatically puts form elements on the scope:  `$scope[formName]`, for example.

It appears my controller is running *before* this form has been established on the scope (`$scope[formName]` is undefined).

Form is not present immediately, yet once you click the button, it is present:
http://plnkr.co/edit/q3RJLfWWcZhm9Y6oQjy3?p=preview

Is there an event to listen to, or some way to wait until the form has loaded?

Would

```
$scope.$watch(formName, ...)
```

work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$timeout` to allow the digest cycle to perform and then gain reference to your form on the scope:

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.doIt();
}, 0);
```

But note that you'll need to inject `$timeout` into your controller:

```
controller('ctrl1', function($scope, $timeout){
```

**Update** here is a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WaokFzb060TweUwqXOBS?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Not sure why this is necessary, but I like this better, because I'm not sure if $watch will fire multiple times.

Comment: It is generally considered bad form to use a watch in a controller, see this article for an in depth explanation: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html

Comment: I would say using $timeout in a controller falls under the same category :)

Comment: @tasseKATT I agree w/ you, but as the OP commented above, it is a one-time smell, not multiple. Also, with the exception of form validation checks, I can't come up w/ a scenario when you would want to access the form directly from the controller.

Comment: Same here. I don't disagree with your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems $scope.$watch will work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/E9170S4k2GIGz6AKAd8n?p=preview

Not sure if this is the "Angular Way".  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I recommend doing a watch and deregistering when the form is initialized, that way your function will run only once. It's either that or a timeout, and in that case I personally prefer a watch. Using a timeout can work too, but in other cases it might not work, for example if a variable is initialized on your scope when a REST call is completed..